# Concatenate two lists elementwise to an n x n matrix

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, elementwise-operations

I have two lists with strings which I want to concatenate elementwise into a n x n matrix. I have tried the below code but this only gives me n x 1 list.

```
row = ['a','b','c']
col = ['a','b','c']

matrix = map(''.join, zip(row,col))
```

The expected output would be a matrix like this:

```
[['aa','ab','ac'],
 ['ba','bb','bc'],
 ['ca','cb','cc']])
```

Is there a solution using either regular python or numpy to accomplish this?

Comment: Take a look at converting your list to numpy and using reshape to get it into the form you want, assuming you have the right output just in a flattened form.

Comment: `[[r+c for r in row] for c in col]`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Regular Python - using string concatenation and list comprehension:

```
matrix = [[x + y for x in row] for y in col]
```

To be compliant with NumPy styling and the desired output use:

```
np.c_[matrix].T
```

Answer (score 4):

If you really want to use NumPy, you could make use of [`meshgrid`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) to do something like this:

```
row_mat, col_mat = numpy.meshgrid(row, col)
concat_mat = numpy.core.defchararray.add(col_mat, row_mat)
```

Comment: Thanks! This executed somewhat faster when I scaled to 30000 items in each list.

Answer (score 3):

Here is a `numpy` one liner:

```
np.add.outer(row,col,dtype="O")
# array([['aa', 'ab', 'ac'],
#        ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'],
#        ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 2):

For a numpy approach:

```
import itertools
np.array([''.join(i) for i in list(itertools.product(row,col))]).reshape(3,3)                                                                                                       

# array([['aa', 'ab', 'ac'],
#       ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'],
#       ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']], dtype='<U2')
```

Answer (score 2):

Taking advantage of the `+` definition for python strings (not numpy string dtype):

```
In [140]: row=np.array(['a','b','c'],object)                                    
In [141]: row[:,None]+row                                                       
Out[141]: 
array([['aa', 'ab', 'ac'],
       ['ba', 'bb', 'bc'],
       ['ca', 'cb', 'cc']], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

For the precise desired output

```
row = ['a','b','c']
col = ['a','b','c']


result = [[y + x for x in row] for y in col]
print(result)
```